# C# regex can't find text with whitespace if input is escaped

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping

While trying to find a bit of text with a single whitespace between two words, I encountered something that seems like a bug. I'm using a pattern like `(abc)\s(abc)`, to find two specific words. Now I'm escaping my input using `Regex.Escape`, but then my regex doesn't match anymore because spaces are escaped (to `\space`), and then not matched. Is this intended?

My text comes from user input, so as far as I know it should be escaped.

To clarify my question, the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Original text: " + text);
Console.WriteLine("Escaped text: " + Regex.Escape(text));
Console.WriteLine("Matches non-escaped text: " + Regex.IsMatch(text, @"(abc)\s(abc)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine("Matches escaped text: " + Regex.IsMatch(Regex.Escape(text), @"(abc)\s(abc)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Gives the following result for input `abc abc`

> Original text: abc abc
>
> Escaped text: abc\ abc
>
> Matches non-escaped text: True
>
> Matches escaped text: False

While I would expect it to still match on spaces

Comment: Why do you `Regex.Escape(text)`? This method is only meant for strings that will be used in a regex pattern to match literal text parts. It adds ``\`` before spaces, right. So you can't expect `\s` to match ``\<SPACE>``. You need to add ``\\`` before ``\s`` in your pattern (i.e. ``@"(abc)\\\s(abc)"``).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So the text for the input of the regular expression doesn't need to be escaped? Now that I think about it, that makes total sense. For some reason my mind just made the connection user-input -> escape it

Comment: *So the text for the input of the regular expression doesn't need to be escaped?* - Correct, just use your first "Matches non-escaped text" code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, makes sense. Should I post an answer to my own question to further expand on this or just remove my question? I think it'd be good to keep it in case someone else does the same and stumbles on this question

Comment: It is my 1562nd consecutive day on SO, regex tag, and I have only seen 1 similar post before. It is not a real issue, IMHO. I vote to close the question as off-topic. Whether or not to delete, you decide.

Answer (score 1):

> My text comes from user input, so as far as I know it should be escaped.

This is a faulty premise. If you assume this, then every time someone uses any of your apps to create a record for an employee named `Shamus A. O'Leary`, they'll probably end up being inserted into the db as `Shamus A\. O\'Leary`, `Shamus A. O&#39;Leary`, `Shamus+A%2E+O'Leary` etc depending on where the data came from and how you decided it needed to be escaped

Just because user provides text doesn't mean it needs to be escaped - you're going to have to apply escaping contextually rather than as a blanket rule based on where text comes from. Generally escaping is used to make sure data can survive being put through some transport channel that doesn't support all the characters, or will try to process some of the characters as having a special meaning when they should not. Instead of hence looking at escaping as something that must be done depending on the source of data, look at it as something that must be done to ensure data reaches a destination unharmed

Regex-wise `(abc)\s(abc)` does not match a string of `abc\ abc`, because of the slash. You've transformed your string from matching X to something else (Y), and then asked the regex parser whether Y matches the regex. It's no more a match than `abc+abc` is a match, going off an assumption that "when URLs are escaped, spaces become pluses, so a plus and a space must mean the same thing to a regex" - the regex engine will just look at the data and say "plus is not a whitespace character; no match". The regex engine won't look at your data and think "hey, if I just unescape this before I run it through the pattern matcher..." and it won't look at your data and think "it's a regex pattern" - a regex pattern expression and data passed to a regex matcher working from that pattern are very different things, and if you want your data to match a described pattern, don't alter the data after you've decided on the pattern

Thus the fault is in transforming the string by running a character replacement (escaping) before asking for the match